# Efficient way of calculating amount of concurrent calls by one user to a distinct phone number using python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a large dataframe of user calls to different phone numbers

```
calls = {
    'user': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
    'number': ['+1 11', '+2 22', '+2 22', '+1 11', '+4 44', '+1 11'],
    'start_time': ['00:00:00', '00:02:00', '00:03:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00'],
    'end_time': ['00:05:00', '00:03:01', '00:05:00', '00:05:00', '00:02:00', '00:02:00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(calls)
```

|  | user | number | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 11 | 00:00:00 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | b | 2 22 | 00:02:00 | 00:03:01 |
| 2 | b | 2 22 | 00:03:00 | 00:05:00 |
| 3 | b | 1 11 | 00:00:00 | 00:05:00 |
| 4 | c | 4 44 | 00:00:00 | 00:02:00 |
| 5 | c | 1 11 | 00:00:00 | 00:02:00 |

And I am trying to calculate max number of concurrent (parallel) calls from one user to a distinct number:

```
res = pd.DataFrame([])
grouped_by_user = df.groupby(['user'])
user_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'number_dict': None})
    
    for user in grouped_by_user.groups:
    user_group = grouped_by_user.get_group(user)
    grouped_by_number = user_group.groupby(['number'])
    number_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'max_calls': None})
    
    for number in grouped_by_number.groups:
        number_group = grouped_by_number.get_group(number)
        calls = []
        for i in number_group.index:
            calls.append(len(number_group[(number_group["start_time"] <= number_group.loc[i, "start_time"]) & (number_group["end_time"] > number_group.loc[i, "start_time"])]))
        number_dict[number]['max_calls'] = max(calls)
    user_dict[user]['number_dict'] = number_dict
    
    tmp_list = []
    for num, calls in number_dict.items():
        tmp_list.append([user, num, calls['max_calls']])
    res = res.append(tmp_list, ignore_index=True)
```

with a resulting dataframe which looks like that:

|  | user | number | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 11 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 1 11 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2 22 | 2 |
| 3 | c | 1 11 | 1 |
| 4 | c | 4 44 | 1 |

But this code is very slow for large dataframes. Is there a better way of doing it? Or how can improve the time efficiency of this code?

Comment: what is the desired result if you have these three calls (same user, same number)? 00:02:00 --> 00:03:01, 00:03:00 --> 00:05:01, 00:05:00 --> 00:07:00. That is, the first call and the third do not overlap, but the first overlaps with the second, and the second overlaps with the third

Comment: How is your expected result different from `df.groupby(['user', 'number']).agg('size')` ?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco it should output 2

Comment: @Mortz df.groupby(['user', 'number']).agg('size') will give me the number of calls of one user to a different numbers. What I want is more fine grained result: one user-one number-one time

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_time"], format='%H:%M:%S')
df["end_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_time"], format='%H:%M:%S')

def fn(x):
    x["tmp1"] = x.apply(
        lambda y: pd.date_range(y["start_time"], y["end_time"], freq="1s"),
        axis=1,
    )

    x = x.explode("tmp1")

    return (
        x.loc[x.duplicated(subset=["tmp1"], keep=False), "tmp1"]
        .value_counts()
        .max()
    )


print(
    df.groupby(["user", "number"])
    .apply(fn)
    .to_frame(name="max")
    .reset_index()
    .fillna(1)
)
```

Prints:

```
  user number  max
0    a  +1 11  1.0
1    b  +1 11  1.0
2    b  +2 22  2.0
3    c  +1 11  1.0
4    c  +4 44  1.0
```

---

With

```py
calls = {
    "user": ["a", "b", "b", "b", "c"],
    "number": ["+1 11", "+1 11", "+1 11", "+1 11", "+1 11"],
    "start_time": ["00:00:00", "00:04:00", "00:00:00", "00:03:00", "00:00:00"],
    "end_time": ["00:05:00", "00:08:00", "00:05:00", "00:05:30", "00:02:00"],
}
```

Prints:

```
  user number  max
0    a  +1 11  1.0
1    b  +1 11  3.0
2    c  +1 11  1.0
```

Comment: thank you very much! even though I cant understand what is going on here (feel free to add more comments/explanations) it works on test cases. But when I am using it on actual data it complains about these lines: `df.groupby(["user","number"]).apply(fn.to_frame(name="max").reset_index().fillna(1`  `x["tmp1"] = x.apply(lambda y: pd.date_range(y["start_time"], y["end_time"], freq="1s"),axis=1)` the error is : `Arguments: ('ValueError', ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index',))`  do you know how to fix it? Thanks in advance